# What can I drink all day in lieu of water?

Tags: water

What can I drink all day which is,

(1) easy to obtain

(2) tasty

(3) help to lose my weight (or, at least doesn't make me gain weight)

I want to drink it whenever I am bored.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a part of the problem is that you drink because you're bored, rather than thirsty. It may be worth trying to break that habit of consuming things for stimulation.

To make your water more interesting, though, you could add:

- A touch of lemon or lime juice
- Low calorie/low sugar squash

You could also try:

- Tea or coffee without milk/cream
- Green teas and herbal teas

Comment: Legit answer. I'd like to add that you wouldn't want to add lemon or lime juice to often during the day since this could damage your teeth over time.

Answer (score 0):

Try lqd+ (or off brand alternatives) - basically flavoring with low calories.

Tho green tea (without sugar) would be better and may help with losing weight a little due to the caffeine.